# Append ng-click to dynamically changed html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a ng-repeat for descriptions that have tags. I use init to filter the tags to rewrite the description with ng-click. However the ng-click doesn't work after. Is this possible?

```
<div ng-repeat="desc in descs">
   <div ng-init="desc.description = getTags(desc.description )">
      {{ desc.description }}
   </div>
</div> 

<script>
$scope.getTags = function(desc) {
   var desc = desc.replace("#tag", '<span ng-click="function">#tag</span>');
   return desc;
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Injected HTML code into AngularJS shall be processed with $compile

See official doc here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-bind-html` but you also need to create one filter that will sanitize that html using `$sce` service `trustAsHtml` method.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="desc in descs">
   <div ng-bind-html="getTags(desc.description) | trustHtml">
   </div>
</div>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('trustHtml', function($sce) { 
  return function(text) {
    $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };
}
```